# Google calendar API V3 update event

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I can perfectly add an event with Google Calendar API V3 as described in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents but I can't figure how to start on the update event process.

I guess I have to select the event (I do have the event ID stored on my DB) and then set the parameters and call an update event. But don't know where to start...

There seems to be very few tutorials around. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I finally got the answer my self. Struggled to read on those Google API Explorer and matching them against the google-api-php-client. Anyway, here it is a simple code to update the description, summary and event color.

```
$apiClient = new apiClient();
$apiClient->setUseObjects(true);
$service   = new apiCalendarService($apiClient);
$events    = $service->events;

$currEvent  = $events->get("primary", $event_id);

$currEvent->setDescription("YOUR FULL DESCRIPTION");
$currEvent->setSummary("YOUR DESIRED SUMMARY - Kind of title");
$currEvent->setColorId(2); // One of the available colors ID

$recurringEvent = $events->update('primary', $event_id, $currEvent);
```

Remember that this code needs to be ran only after authentication.
Hope it helps someone. It did me ;)